# Laravel policy too few arguments passed to UserPolicy

Tags: php, laravel

I've got a Laravel 9 project being used as an API. I'm using the Laravel Spatie Permissions package to perform permission and role checks. I've set up a Laravel policy called `UserPolicy`, and thus far my policy methods are working fine, apart from when I attempt to authorize my `show` function.

My API only passes the model's ID, and this is fine, also, I already have my user by this point. I'm checking to see whether the logged in user has the ability to view another user that may not be their-self in the platform here.

The error:

> Too few arguments to function App\Policies\UserManagement\UserPolicy::view(), 1 passed in /Users/ryanholton/Sites/lespro-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php on line 798 and exactly 2 expected

Here's my controller action:

```php
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $this->authorize('view', User::class);

    $user = User::with('roles')->find($id);

    if (!$user) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'User not found or invalid user ID'
        ], 404);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'user' => $user
    ], 200);
}
```

And my policy:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Policies\UserManagement;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class UserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any models.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response|bool
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        if ($user->can('user_index')) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $model
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response|bool
     */
    public function view(User $user, User $model)
    {
        if ($user->can('user_show')) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create models.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response|bool
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        if ($user->can('user_store')) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $model
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response|bool
     */
    public function update(User $user, User $model)
    {
        if ($user->can('user_update')) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $model
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response|bool
     */
    public function delete(User $user, User $model)
    {
        if ($user->can('user_destroy')) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for `authorize` method you have to pass `$user` instance

```
$user = User::with('roles')->find($id);

 $this->authorize('view',$user);
```

and in your policy , remove extra user param

```
 public function view(User $user)
    {
        if ($user->can('user_show')) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that only one parameter was passed, although the existing method expects two.
Perhaps it's not at all obvious to you which method is called - it is the ***view*** method of the **UserPolicy** class. 
If we pay attention to it, we will indeed see that the method expects two parameters.

```
public function view(User $user, User $model)
```

Try removing the last option - that should help. Your method will looks:

```
public function view(User $user)
```